# Check If one datetime lies between two datetimes python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to check if one datetime lies between two datetimes, most of the cases return true, but in below case it return false whereas it should return true, how can I check it in proper way.

```
time1=1900-01-01 08:30:00
time2=1900-01-01 00:00:00
inbetween=1900-01-01 20:00:00

    if (time1<=inbetween<=time2):  # if 12 hour format (8:30AM<8:00PM<12:AM) it should be true
        print("True")
        return True
    else:
        print("False")
        return False
```

in above case inbetween lies between time1 and time 2 so it should return True but it return False.
How can I check.
NOTE: the date will always remain same so I have to check it on the time basis.

Comment: ...`inbetween` is after `time1` and `time2`

Comment: `time2 is 12AM of 1st` and `time1 is 8.30AM of 1st` but `inbetween is 8PM of 1st`. So its False only

Comment: if time2 is 12:00 AM then time2 date should be like **"1900-01-02 00:00:00"**, I assume that you are searching **"1900-01-01 20:00:00"** in between **"1900-01-01 08:30:00"** and **"1900-01-02 00:00:00"**. At this Case it should return **"True"**

Comment: in time2 you should use `02` as day or `23:59:59` as time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help:

In your implementation, what happening is that `inbetween` come between `time2` and `time1`, not `time1` and `time2`. To fix this, you can set, `time2` to `1900-01-01 23:59:59` or the next day.